# Is this colored (brown, red, yellow) and hairy caterpillar dangerous for my strawberries?

Tags: identification, pests

I found this caterpillar on a strawberry-plant-leaf. The leaf had a lot of holes - I assume it was caused by it.

The caterpillar is about 2.5cm long and has a diameter of ~5mm (without the hairs). It is quite hairy. Most of the body hair is white, except two wisps on each side of the body, one of it it is yellow, the other one black. The body is brown and white/grey with red dots. It is has 4 yellow big wisp of hair on its back. It seems to have 2 black eyes - at least as far as I could see.

Is this one dangerous for my strawberries or my garden in general?

*click to enlarge* (intentially left small in the question - not sure if these image can be shocking for sensitive people)

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Vapourer moth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgyia_antiqua) larvae - they feed on fruit foliage and fruitlets, so you might want to get rid of them from your strawberries. Best to pick them off when you see them, though there's probably a pesticide spray suitable for use on fruit and veg that'll do the job if you really want.